# Есть ли способ АВТОМАТИЧЕСКОГО отслеживания изменения Навигационного свойства для внешнего ключа при ДОБАВЛЕНИИ новых данных?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Возьмём самый простой пример.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; } //внешний ключ

    public Company Company { get; set; }  // навигационное свойство
}
```

```
using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
{
    var company = db.Companies.First();

    try
    {
        User tom = new User { Name = "Tom", Company = company };
        db.Users.Add(tom);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Допустим, что после чтения данных из БД `company= db.Companies.First()`, кто-то ПОМЕНЯЛ название компании.
И тогда при выполнении кода

```
User tom = new User { Name = "Tom", Company = company };
db.Users.Add(tom);
db.SaveChanges();
```

никак не отслеживается, что `company` ПОМЕНЯЛАСЬ!

Есть ли способ АВТОМАТИЧЕСКОГО отслеживания изменились ли данные в таблице Company?
Что-то на подобие атрибутов `[Timestamp]` и `[ConcurrencyCheck]`?

Или каждый раз придётся самому проверять все навигационные свойства что они изменились?

Как правильно делать это на практике? В больших БД.

Comment: Допустим мы это отловили. Но ведь название компании всё равно может быть изменено уже после вставки юзера с правильной компанией. Или главное на момент вставки обеспечить правильное название?

Comment: Да, конечно, потом кто-то может изменить данные,
но на момент ввода новых данных о пользователе (в данном примере) , мне кажется, оператор должен чётко знать что он добавляет в БД

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать повышенный уровень изоляции транзакций.
В этом случае другие транзакции не смогут вклиниться между нашими `First` и `SaveChanges`.

```
using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
{
    var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
    
    var company = db.Companies.First(c => c.Name == "A");

    try
    {
        User tom = new User { Name = "Tom", Company = company };
        db.Users.Add(tom);
        db.SaveChanges();

        tran.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tran.Rollback();
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Оправдано ли это - я не уверен. Ведь название компании всё равно может быть изменено уже после выполнения этого кода. Конечно, где-то в истории (если она ведётся) могут остаться правильные записи.

---

Чистый EF Core не позволяет делать вставки с условиями на стороне сервера.
Я советую посмотреть на ORM [linq2db](https://linq2db.github.io/). Она позволяет такие инсёрты.
Понимаю, понимаю... Перейти на другую (правильную) ОРМ (вместо кривой) - это немыслимое дело. Но тогда хотя бы используйте расширение 
[linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)
. Оно включено в официальный список [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/).

Comment: Согласен, наверно, в 99% случаев это не оправдано...
Подумаю... СПАСИБО!
На linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore посмотрю)

Comment: @Andrey чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.